# Using grep to get 12 letter alphabet only lines

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Using grep

How many 12 letter - alphabet only lines are in testing.txt?

excerpt of testing.txt

```
tyler1
Tanktop_Paedo
xyz2@geocities.com
milt@uole.com
justincrump
cranges10
namer@uole.com
soulfunkbrotha
timetolearnz
hotbooby@geocities.com
Fire_Crazy
helloworldad
dingbat@geocities.com
```

from this excerpt, I want to get a result of 2. (helloworldad, and timetolearnz)

I want to check every line and grep only those that have 12 characters in each line. I can't think of a way to do this with grep though.

For the alphabet only, I think I can use

```
grep [A-Za-z] testing.txt
```

However, how do I make it so only the characters [A-Za-z] show up in those 12 characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with extended regex **-E** and by specifying that the match is exactly **{12}** characters from start **^** to finish **$**

```
$ grep -E "^[A-Za-z]{12}$" testing.txt
timetolearnz
helloworldad
```

Or if you want to get the count **-c** of the lines you can use

```
$ grep -cE "^[A-Za-z]{12}$" testing.txt
2
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep` supports whole-line match and counting, e.g.:

```
grep -xc '[[:alpha:]]\{12\}' testing.txt
```

Output:

```
2
```

The `[:alpha:]` character class is another way of saying `[A-Za-z]`. See section 3.2 of the the info pages: `info grep 'Regular Expressions' 'Character Classes and Bracket Expressions'` for more on this subject. Or look it up in [the pdf manual online](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.pdf).